# Unable to store items with arrays in azure cosmosdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to add an item as per microsoft document in azure cosmosdb. This item will have array data for one of the field. "Save" button is disabled.. Looks like something is missing. Can you please help

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "What's new in the coolest Cloud",
    "summary": "A blog post by someone real famous",
    "comments": [
        {"id": 1, "author": "anon", "comment": "something useful, I'm sure"},
        {"id": 2, "author": "bob", "comment": "wisdom from the interwebs"},
       
        {"id": 100001, "author": "jane", "comment": "and on we go ..."},
        {"id": 1000000001, "author": "angry", "comment": "blah angry blah angry"},
        
        {"id": ∞ + 1, "author": "bored", "comment": "oh man, will this ever end?"},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Aside from the extraneous comma (a typo): you've introduced an "unbounded array" antipattern - if you have an overabundance of comments in your array, you run the risk of exceeding maximum document size. You've also introduced a repeated property name (`id` as a property within your comment array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace / encode the special character '∞'.
If you remove it, you are able to save the document.

Comment: I changed as suggested... still issue persists

Comment: {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "What's new in the coolest Cloud",
    "summary": "A blog post by someone real famous",
    "comments": [
        {"id": 1, "author": "anon", "comment": "something useful, I'm sure"},
        {"id": 2, "author": "bob", "comment": "wisdom from the interwebs"},
        {"id": 100001, "author": "jane", "comment": "and on we go ..."},
        {"id": 1000000001, "author": "angry", "comment": "blah angry blah angry"},
        {"id": 1, "author": "bored", "comment": "oh man, will this ever end?"},
    ]
}

Comment: The json is not valid! Please remove a ',' at the end:

}, ] } -> }]}

Comment: Here's an online JSON validator:
https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thanks Markus, I late observed that.. you are correct